# Set fixed value for Hibernate insert in Oracle view

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am create a view in oracle 10g like this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW vw_pikap_approle
AS
   SELECT approle_id, approle_name, creation_timestamp,1 is_pikap
     FROM approle
    WHERE is_pikap = 1
/
```

but after inserting

```
INSERT INTO vw_pikap_approle (approle_id, approle_name, creation_timestamp)
     VALUES (hibernate_sequence.NEXTVAL, 'dddd', SYSDATE)
```

is_pikap is 0 ( as default in DB) , so is_pikap is fixed in view as 1.

Is there any solution for setting fixed value while inserting in Oracle view

This need is because of reducing Hibernate mapping in java application.

I need a hibernate or view solution for this problem.

I am using this mapping for may .hbm.xml:

```
<property
        name="isPikap"
        type="int"
        column="IS_PIKAP"
        not-null="true"
        length="1"
        formula="1"
        />
```

and in my java entity:

```
private int isPikap = 1;
public int getIsPikap() {
    return isPikap;
}
public void setIsPikap(int i) {
    isPikap=1;
}
```

but generated query with hibernate insert is:

```
Hibernate: insert into VW_PIKAP_APPROLE (APPROLE_NAME, APPROLE_ID) values (?, ?)
```

so when i using debugger the isPikap value of java entity is 1!

Comment: Can't you just set `DEFAULT 1` on the underlying table and not include the column in the view?

Comment: no. it is impossible. because underlying table is a general for many subsystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't insert data into this view because is_pikap is derived from an expression.
With Hibernate I suppose you can create your view mapping making is_pikap final and initialized to 1

```
@Entity
@Table("vw_pikap_approle")
class vw_pikap_approle {
  @Column(name="is_pikap")
  private final int is_pikap = 1;

  /* Other properties with accessors  */
}
```

Comment: what about mapping with xml?

Comment: Use a Formula `<property name="is_pikap" formula="1" type="int"/>`

Comment: Default value is not available in xml. Remove formula from xml and set is_pikap to fixed value,then insert (remember to change your view code to made view insertable). I think this is the only way